# Electron jump into a transistor to read qubit state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, semiconductor-physics, quantum-computer, electronics

Prof. Andrea Morello, a quantum physicist, in one of its quantum computer models uses the spin of the outermost electron in a phosphorus atom to represent a qubit. This atom is embedded to a transitor.

In a youtube video he explains how to read the qubit state. He says that if the electron has the spin up (wich is the higher energy state so |1> state) it can jump into the transistor because it has more energy than all the others. So now the phosphorus atom has a positive charge and it can be seen because of a more positive voltage on the transistor gate.

I don't understand why the electron can jump because of it's higher energy than other transistor electrons. Someone can explain me why? I'am absolutely not a physicist but the quantum computer topic is really interesting.

Comment: Which Youtube video?

Comment: So, how do we answer the question without using physics? If I said you vary the gate bias until the spin up state can tunnel (but not spin down), does that help you understand it better?

Comment: @JonCuster - Perhaps try to help them understand what it means to "tunnel" and why you can exclude a specific spin state using this technique?

Comment: I'am a computer scientist so I have studied physics but I can't define myself a physicist. I hope you can help me using formulas but explaining them.

Comment: If one spin state has a higher energy than another, then there is a local or global magnetic field.

Comment: Ok but why the electron jumps?

Comment: @Maghio As somebody mentioned above, the process probably involves tunneling into the transistor structure. I can't tell which particular setup you are referring to, but you can find a friendly intro to tunneling in quantum devices at http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-2/quantum-devices/